# How to fix "Npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected string in JSON at position 228.."

Tags: javascript

I am trying to start NPM after installing it but the start errors out.

I couldn't find syntactical errors in the 'package.json' file
I couldn't find the error log
I tried reinstalling
I tried clearing my cache
All without success

Here is my 'package.json' file:

```
{
  "name": "git-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "test json file",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "lite-server": "^2.4.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run lite"
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    "dev": "lite-server"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/Master-Hippo/Front-End_Web_UI_Frameworks_and_Tools.git"
  },
  "author": "Master-Hippo",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/Master-Hippo/Front-        
End_Web_UI_Frameworks_and_Tools/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/Master-Hippo/Front-    
End_Web_UI_Frameworks_and_Tools#readme"
```

Here is the error log:

```
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected string in JSON at position 228 while parsing 
'{
npm ERR! JSON.parse   "name": "git-test",
npm ERR! JSON.parse   "version": "1.'
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! JSON.parse package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
```

And, although the message says an error log was created in a specific folder, none actually exists in said folder.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: the `package.json` that you post is not valid [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: Thanks Alexandre Rodrigues. It was an invalid JSON format and several of the elements didn't have ',''s afterward.    Please post that as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I hope that helped to fix the issue.

Comment: Can you better format the json in your question? Because not all of it is within a code block format.

Comment: I wonder on what editor you're working. Every modern editor / IDE spots this type of errors, so consider changing it

Answer (score 3):

Try validate your `package.json` with [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/)

I guess that your file could be like this:

```
{
    "name": "git-test",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "test json file",
    "main": "index.js",
    "dependencies": {},
    "devDependencies": {
        "lite-server": "^2.4.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "npm run lite",
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "dev": "lite-server"
    },
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git+https://github.com/Master-Hippo/Front-End_Web_UI_Frameworks_and_Tools.git"
    },
    "author": "Master-Hippo",
    "license": "ISC",
    "bugs": {
        "url ": "https://github.com/Master-Hippo/Front-End_Web_UI_Frameworks_and_Tools/issues"
    },
    "homepage": "https://github.com/Master-Hippo/Front-End_Web_UI_Frameworks_and_Tools#readme"
}
```

Comment: Why? The error message already says it is invalid and states what line and character the error is one.

Comment: @Quentin In this case, but sometimes the error isn't very evident. So vealidating in jsonlint is a wonderful idea even for the future people

Comment: @Sisir — JSONLint is going to give the same error message!

Answer (score 0):

Also note sometimes this issue can occur even if there is no missing comma in **package.json** file.
This occurs due to node version.

In my case, I hade node version 14.17.1 installed on my system and the repo was working in 16.xx.xx version and I faced this issue, and once i upgraded node the problem got resolved.

So also keep this point in mind.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Your **package.json** should be valid **json** like this:

```
{
    "name": "git-test",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "test json file",
    "main": "index.js",
    "dependencies": {},
    "devDependencies": {
        "lite-server": "^2.4.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "npm run lite",
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "dev": "lite-server"
    },
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git+https://github.com/Master-Hippo/Front-End_Web_UI_Frameworks_and_Tools.git"
    },
    "author": "Master-Hippo",
    "license": "ISC",
    "bugs": {
        "url": "https://github.com/Master-Hippo/Front-End_Web_UI_Frameworks_and_Tools/issues"
    },
    "homepage": "https://github.com/Master-Hippo/Front-End_Web_UI_Frameworks_and_Tools#readme"
}
```

There were a few commas missing.